# Strange Folder Appeared, Can't be deleted

Tags: windows-7

After some time I created a folder I noticed that there was exact duplicate of this folder which was **Exact** same **Format, Name, Direction**, I can't **Delete** it, **Move** it or **Rename** it, it shows up this error:

[image]

I am able though to open it.

Really weird never seen anything like that before.

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Yep, I did. Also to be honest I still don't know how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

how old your harddrive??

that folder is not exist, it just an error detection

remove it use Unlocker, and  if your harddrive was pretty old you should replace it

Answer (score 0):

How about running chkdsk /r on your hard drive under an elevated command prompt, this might remove those inconsistent file structures.